# Select a key value from MySQL table where one row with the key is greater than another

Tags: mysql, sql

So assume I have this table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|  key  |  id   |  type  |  value |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|   1   |   1   |  cool  |    5   |
|   2   |   1   |  uncool|    10  |
|   3   |   2   |  none  |    7   |
|   4   |   2   |  cool  |    23  |
|   5   |   2   |  uncool|    4   |
|   6   |   3   |  cool  |    6   |
|   7   |   3   |  uncool|    3   |
|   8   |   3   |  unapp |    52  |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Note that the key column is just the unique identifier, and is not relevant for what I am trying to do.

I want to find the ids (key) where the cool type value is greater than the uncool type value, ignoring any other rows.
So the result would be

```
+------+
|  id  |
+------+
|  2   |
|  3   |
+------+
```

I spent a few hours with the SQL editor open, messing with HAVING and GROUP BY and haven't been able to find a solution.
Is there a way to do this without resorting to making queries and then performing checks in another language, or is this the only solution?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: As I said in the question, the key is `id`

Comment: The primary key would just be an incremental value. I'll edit the question to include it.

Comment: If a row with 'cool' is present and a row with 'uncool' is not present for some `id` does this value must be returned?

Comment: the rows cool and uncool are always present, there will never be a case where they are not, however someone answered this already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the  `id` and take only those having the condition you describe.

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having max(case when `type` = 'cool' then `value` end) > 
       max(case when `type` = 'uncool' then `value` end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t2.type = 'uncool'
WHERE t1.type = 'cool'
  AND (t1.value > t2.value OR t2.value IS NULL)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=033be4a6364e28e78a421625c0bf70cc)

If `uncool` is not present (for example, remove row with `key=5`) then my solution will give 2 rows whereas another solutions will give 1 row only.

Comment: After checking the demo from Akina's answer and the explanation I agree with Akina's solution. I suggest to OP @MCterra to check this fiddle and explanation again...

Comment: juergen d's solution solves this with a simple logical check and doesn't require any joins, and I can far more easily see how it works.

Comment: @MCterra juergen d's and my queries realizes different logic. You have/need only one definite logic, so you must use a query which fully matches it. If this is studying task then it is very useful to understand the difference between realized logics - even more important than simply get an answer.